# Percentage of time of an evaluation used to perform the evaluation

Tags: time-management, software-evaluation

I often need to evaluate the time required to do software modifications and include this time in the evaluation.

What is the average percentage of the time evaluated that should be used to perform the evaluation ?

For example, if I evaluate the testing time of a modification to 9 hours and it takes me 1 hour to do the evaluation my evaluation will be 10 hours. This mean that 10% of the evaluated time has been used for the evaluation.

I know that there is no "Magic Number or Ideal Amount of time" but i was just hoping to have a range of value according to the experience of people working in the same field as me. I have no Co-Worker to compare my results so it is hard to evaluate myself.

My Estimate Need to be around 80% Accurate: If i estimate 100h it can take between 80h and 120h.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the estimation process: what happens when management asks, "How long will it take?"  The amount of time spent doing time estimates depends entirely on how accurate and reliable those estimates need to be.

For example, if I say, "I don't know how long," my estimate consumes zero time and is 100 percent reliable (I'm right every time I provide this estimate), but it has no accuracy.

On the other hand, if I simply write the feature and provide my estimate as the amount of time it took to write it, my estimate will be 100 percent accurate and 100 percent reliable, but it will take up 100 percent of the development time.

A *useful* estimate will be somewhere in between.  There isn't an "ideal amount of time" to do an estimate or an evaluation, other than the fact that time spent doing paperwork is time spent not developing new features.  You have to find a sensible balance.

Comment: Thanks, i know that there is no "Magic Number or Ideal Amount of time" but i was just hoping to have a range of value according to the experience of people working in the same field as me. I have no Co-Worker to compare my results so it is hard to evaluate myself. To Answer your question my Estimate Need to be around 80% Accurate